# Absolute path of Bazel $(location) macro

Tags: java, bazel

I am using `$(location)` to pass the location of a built java_library to my java_binary (targets simplified):

```
java_binary(
    name = "my_bin",
    main_class = "Bin",
    srcs = [
        "Bin.java"
    ],
    deps = [
        ":my_lib"
    ],
    jvm_flags = [
        "-Dmy_library_path=$(location :my_lib)"
    ]
)

java_library(
    name = "my_lib",
    srcs = [
        "Lib.java"
    ]
)
```

It looks like this location is relative to the original running location, which means when I use  `--run_under` to run my target in the current directory, it breaks and the location is invalid.

Is there a way to get the absolute location, or is there a more portable way to pass the jar path to my binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a [sh_binary](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/shell.html) to wrap it, and then use [runfiles.bash](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash) to find the paths at runtime. Something like this (after renaming `my_bin` to `my_bin_impl` and removing the `jvm_flags`):

```py
sh_binary(
  name = "my_bin",
  srcs = [
    "my_bin_wrapper.sh",
  ],
  data = [
    ":my_bin_impl",
  ],
  deps = [
    "@bazel_tools//tools/bash/runfiles",
  ],
)
```

and for `my_bin_wrapper.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# --- begin runfiles.bash initialization v2 ---
# Copy-pasted from the Bazel Bash runfiles library v2.
set -uo pipefail; f=bazel_tools/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash
source "${RUNFILES_DIR:-/dev/null}/$f" 2>/dev/null || \
  source "$(grep -sm1 "^$f " "${RUNFILES_MANIFEST_FILE:-/dev/null}" | cut -f2- -d' ')" 2>/dev/null || \
  source "$0.runfiles/$f" 2>/dev/null || \
  source "$(grep -sm1 "^$f " "$0.runfiles_manifest" | cut -f2- -d' ')" 2>/dev/null || \
  source "$(grep -sm1 "^$f " "$0.exe.runfiles_manifest" | cut -f2- -d' ')" 2>/dev/null || \
  { echo>&2 "ERROR: cannot find $f"; exit 1; }; f=; set -e
# --- end runfiles.bash initialization v2 ---

exec "$(rlocation "my_repository/my_package/my_bin_impl")" --jvm_flag=-Dmy_library_path="$(rlocation "my_repository/my_package/my_lib")" "$@"
```

If you want to do multiple binaries like this, you can wrap generating the wrapper and creating the `sh_binary` in a [macro](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html).